# Sliding Content above page instead of scrolling down to it

Tags: html, css, scroll, sliding

Hey Im making a website that will have a fixed background of 1366px by 768px that doesnt move but has a content area that will move either up or down by pressing on the nav. The problem is that I have a smoothscrolling jquery script running and only works if i dont limit the overflow of the wrapper(where content is), and it scrolls down to the div i tell it to. I want it to push the content above the top of the page instead. Am I doing something wrong or is this doable?

Thanks in advance.

The site link is [www.andrewapperley.ca/JessicaP/](http://www.andrewapperley.ca/JessicaP/)

Comment: I made it the way I want it but the scolling doesnt work, just so you have a better idea of what I want. [link] (http://www.andrewapperley.ca/JessicaP2/)

Comment: are you trying to keep the menu and background image in view and just have the content scroll up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using negative top(ex. top: -400px ) trick for pushing the content above the top.That's how we create attention messages(pop ins) in browsers.

Comment: I dont want to use a PX amount because if the client adds content it would change the px count and she wouldnt know how to change a Javascript file

Comment: actually,we dont use exact "px" values in doing this.We first calculate the offset of the element which you want to set on the screen then give the parent container negative top with that amount.It'll work even if she adds new content.pure jquery you know

Comment: Just go through this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/12/flexible-slide-to-top-accordion/ .Maybe you find something similar

Comment: but that accordion is really what im looking for but ill keep trying

Answer (score 0):

i put the background in an img tag and made it the width and height 100% of the window with zindex of -1 so it stays and the content scrolls, thank you for your help and anyone else that looked at this.